# The fastest way to sort the elements in each row of a matrix?

Tags: r, performance, sorting, matrix, apply

I have a matrix with a couple million rows and about 40 columns.

I want to sort the elements in each row in decreasing order. Thus, the element with the highest value of each row should be in the first column.

To do this I can use the `apply` function:

```
set.seed(1)
mm <- replicate(10, rnorm(20)) #random matrix with 20 rows and 10 columns
mm.sorted <- apply(mm,1,sort,decreasing=T)
```

But for a very large matrix this approach takes a very long time.

Are there different approaches to speed up the sorting of elements in rows?

Comment: You can look at the guidance for parallelization here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html I'm guessing it will look like `lapply(split(mm, row(mm)), sort)` but replacing `lapply` with some variant, like mclapply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use package data.table:

```
set.seed(1)
mm <- matrix(rnorm(1000000*40,0,10),ncol=40) 
library(data.table)
system.time({
  d <- as.data.table(mm)
  d[, row := .I]
  d <- melt(d, id.vars = "row") #wide to long format
  setkey(d, row, value) #sort
  d[, variable := paste0("V", ncol(mm):1)] #decreasing order

  #back to wide format and coerce to matrix
  msorted <- as.matrix(dcast(d, row ~ variable)[, row := NULL]) 
})
#user  system elapsed 
#4.96    0.59    5.62
```

If you could keep it as a long-format data.table (i.e., skip the last step), it would take about 2 seconds on my machine.

For comparison, timings of @qjgods' answer on my machine:

```
#user  system elapsed 
#3.71    2.08    8.81
```

Note that using `apply` (or parallel versions of it) transposes the matrix.

Comment: I don't know how optimized reshape2:::melt.matrix is, but that might be another option for the first few steps, like `d = melt(mm); setDT(d, key=c("row","value"))`. And there might be an `acast` or something for the way back

Comment: It is a very nice solution. But although I examine the code several times, I can't understand how setkey sort it and how dcast transform it back to wide format. Can you please explain it or suggest a tutorial?

Comment: That's literally what setting a key means: sorting data and marking it sorted. Look at the documentation of setkey and dcast.

Answer (score 7):

use the parallel package to speed up

```
library(parallel)
data<-matrix(rnorm(1000000*40,0,10),ncol=40) 
cl <- makeCluster(8)  # 8 is the number of CPU
system.time({
   parApply(cl,data,1,sort,decreasing=T)
 })
   user  system elapsed 
   9.68   10.11   29.87 
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one clever way:

```
res <- matrix(mm[order(row(mm), -mm)], nrow = nrow(mm), byrow = TRUE)
```

Also faster than others:

```
system.time(
  res <- matrix(mm[order(row(mm), -mm)], nrow=nrow(mm), byrow=TRUE)
)
 user  system elapsed
1.910   0.254   2.170
```